# "Declared but not used" variable in for's condition expression

Tags: go

My intuitive approach:
https://play.golang.org/p/6xzg7TK1IH

and it doesn't work.

Can you share some alternative ways?

Comment: if variable not needed use underscore https://play.golang.org/p/S9kzv_dBlk

Comment: duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used-from-golang. There's a nice explanation of why go language creators added this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `:=` which discards the previous contents of the variables. You don't use `morelines` in that scope, thus the error message.

If you declare your variables beforehand and don't use `:=`, it works fine. The function `ReadLine()` might not do what you think it should do.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    bio := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    var line []byte
    var err error
    moreline := true
    for moreline {
        line, moreline, err = bio.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a variable (`moreline`) which you don't use it. You have two options here: either to replace the `moreline` with underscore, which means you can omit the return value.

```
for moreline {
        line, _, err := bio.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(line)
}
```

But a better option will be to use the `ReadScanner`, `ReadBytes('\n')` or `ReadString('\n')`.

Checking the `bufio.go` file this is what you get as description for the `ReadLine` method:

> ReadLine is a low-level line-reading primitive. Most callers should
>   use ReadBytes('\n') or ReadString('\n') instead or use a Scanner.

Calling `UnreadByte` after `ReadLine` will always unread the last byte read (possibly a character belonging to the line end) even if that byte is not part of the line returned by `ReadLine`. `ReadLine` either returns a non-nil line or it returns an error, never both.

So this would be a better option:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bio)

for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", line)
}
```