# How to declare struct first and initiliaze it later in switch statement?

Tags: go, struct

I would like to declare a struct first and then initialize it inside a switch statement. The code I've written so far shows [declared and not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used-from-golang) errors. However, I think the problem is different in my case and related to scope of declaration.

Could somebody please help me to make the below code work?

**Car.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

type Car struct{
    Name string
    Price int
}

func main(){
    name := "Fiat"
    car := &Car{}
    switch name {
        case "Fiat":
            car := &Car{
                Name : "Fiat",
                Price: 600000,
            }
        case "Mercedes-benz":
            car := &Car{
                Name : "Mercedes-benz",
                Price: 5600000,
            }
        default:
            car := &Car{
                Name : "Toyota",
                Price: 1000000,
            }

    }
    fmt.Println("Car Name : " + car.Name + " Price : " + strconv.Itoa(car.Price));
}
```

**Errors**

```
 $go run Car.go
./Car.go:19: car declared and not used
./Car.go:24: car declared and not used
./Car.go:29: car declared and not used
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the scope of your variable declarations. You are shadowing the variable declaration inside the switch statement.

Simply change `car:=` to `car=` and you will be fine. You might also want to change `car:=&Car{}` to `var car *Car`. This will make your intent clearer and avoid an unnecessary allocation (as you are creating a new object which is never used).

Read about [blocks & scopes](http://www.tapirgames.com/blog/golang-block-and-scope) and see the [scoping](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) section of the Go language reference.