# Disable vscode clear/remove not used code when save file

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I save file, VSCode auto cleans the not used code, How to Disable it? I want to make VSCode not to  delete any line of my code.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964368/80428

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After finding and testing, it can be configured at  `Workspace Settings > Go configurartion`, override `"go.formatOnSave": false,` on the right side, disable formatting then the code will not be auto cleaned.

[image]

EDIT: Later then I meet [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used-from-golang) .

Comment: This is not a solution... now the code will not be formatted at all!

Comment: This also happens in JavaScript for any code following a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The setting `source.organizeImports` removes unused imports when you save. Set the value to "never" to prevent removing unused imports.

```
{
    "[go]": {
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": "never"
        }
    },
}
```

See also: vscode-go documentation https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/advanced#formatting-code-and-organizing-imports

Answer (score 0):

Go to Visual Studio Code's settings page in JSON format, then remove this line or update it with `false`

```
"source.fixAll": true, // you can make it false as well
```

this line you will find inside of this object

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {

},
```

If it still does not work as expected, then check that your repo may contain a `.vscode` directory with a `settings.json` file that may contain the configuration and change it there.