# Prevent deleting dead code during Auto Format on Save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the magic configuration for allowing a file to be auto-formatted upon a Save operation, but stop / disable / prevent VSCode from deleting dead code?

Sometimes I want to deliberately throw an exception in the middle of a function, for debugging purposes but am forced to comment out all following code in order not to get it deleted.

What's worse is that sometime I save while the editor didn't yet recover from some error in the code, thinks the code still contains an error, and causes code deletions which should not happen in the first place. I found myself too many times pulling up git in order to restore good code which was wrongly deleted.

Is there a clear "do not delete dead code" option to switch on?

UPDATE:

1. Running Prettier (the file's formatter) from command line did not delete dead code.
2. Trying to disable all extensions didn't help either. The dead code is still deleted upon save.

Comment: That seems a concrete feature of the specific formatter you are using. Do you know which one it is? You can run the "Format Document With..." command to get a list of available options.

Comment: Thank you @ÁlvaroGonzález, I thought this is a VSCode code behavior. I have "Prettier" enabled. If that's what's killing my dead code then I couldn't yet find a way to disable it.

Comment: UPDATE: @ÁlvaroGonzález  Following your comment I created an example and ran Prettier from the command line. Prettier auto-formatted the file, but didn't delete dead-code. Seems like the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case solved.

I can't pinpoint the exact package that's causing it but it seems to be related to either **ESLint** or **Prettier**.

Turns out that the project's Github repo contains a `.vscode` directory with a settings.json that contains the following configuration:

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  }
}
```

I already saw posts saying to add `"source.fixAll": false` to VSCode's general `settings.json` file, but it had no effect when I did.

Setting the flag to `false` did the trick

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": false
  }
}
```

Note: Adding the above block to the general `settings.json` had no effect as well. I had to modify the local `.vscode/settings.json` file to get it to work.

Comment: I suggest you edit the answer and explain what extension provides the `source.fixAll` setting so whoever googles here in the future can easily know whether it's his case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I updated the answer. It's either ESLint or Prettier but I can't tell exactly which one. This thing's been bugging me for months. I posted a question then shared my solution. Is not specifying the exact related package really worth the down-vote?

Comment: thank you! i donno who and why did it but he make me mad. stupid idea

Comment: If set `"source.fixAll": false`, No code will be formatted.

Answer (score 5):

`source.fixAll` activates also TS fixes, which are somehow too aggressive to use on save. Only enabling eslint fixes with `source.fixAll.eslint` is a good compromise - it will still report dead code (no-unreachable) but not delete it.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109530

Comment: worked for me! is it a hidden option in setting.json? because it can't be sugguested.