# How to avoid "declared and not used" when using the variable only in other packages?

Tags: go

I saw this post
[How to avoid annoying error "declared and not used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used?rq=1)

but I don't know if this is the right way to handle the error,
when I use the variable in other packages.

for example, in case I use `Connect()` only in other packages, I don't use variable `db` in this package.

```
func Connect() {
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Berlin2018@/jplatform")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear from the question what you want to achieve. Please provide more information on what you want and what you don't

Comment: I want to use this function ```Connect()``` in another package but variable ```db``` causes "declared and not used" error in the package it was initialized in.

Comment: Your variable `db` cannot possibly be used from another package--or even in the same package, outside of the `Connect()` function... so I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `Connect`, so that you can return the `*sql.DB` session to connect to the database.

Comment: @ShiningGo you should look at the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way to avoid the "annoying" declared and not used you shouldn't declare a variable that you are not using, if for instance you are not need to use an variable that returns from a function you can use _ to ignore it.
like in here:

```
func Connect() {
  _, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Berlin2018@/jplatform")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
}
```

But you will need use your DB instance at other parts of your code
so you will need to declare your variable with like that:

```
var DBInstance *sql.db
```

and then you will be able to access the db pointer from anywhere in the package

so full example will be:

```
var DBInstance *sql.db
func Connect() {
      db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Berlin2018@/jplatform")
      if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for! to make the variable Global.

Comment: Except you maybe shouldn't use a global var: https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2017/06/09/theory-of-modern-go.html ;-)

Comment: Saying you "should" use global variables is bad, IMO.  True, this addresses the specific issue brought up by the OP, but it's usually bad practice.

Comment: maybe that global wasn't in place. 
so how would you guys manage the db instance?
@TommyF I read the article and in there he send a pointer to the db as an argument in the end, but he still had to declare it as a var somewhere, so what is the best practice in your opinion?