# How do I get the following Golang MCTS example running?

Tags: go, artificial-intelligence, monte-carlo-tree-search

I am trying to grasp the flow of this implementation and figure out how to run this MCTS implementation: https://github.com/int8/gomcts/blob/master/README.md.

Steps taken: I have followed the Readme but it errors out. I posted an issue on the Github repository but I have received no response. I have skimmed the Golang documentation but nothing jumps out to me.

Can anyone jumpstart me so I can get the code started and slowly work out the program flow with console print outs?

Some background on me: My knowledge of Golang is new, and programming experience is just blossoming as of late. I have some Python experience and JavaScript experience.

Thanks for your time! I will add more as I research and if I can eventually generalize this question to help others I will.

Answer (score 0):

The source code indicates, "use chosenAction further". One of the issues that you will encounter just following the Read me, is that a variable is left unused.

Solutions to prevent the error generated as a result can be found here: [How to avoid annoying error "declared and not used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used#21744129)

In summary, there is no bug in the code, just an incomplete example.