# Is there an idiomatic way to index through a type-asserted interface in Go?

Tags: go, type-assertion

I'm working towards implementing a concurrent `string` and `byte` reader in Go. The purpose of this is to allow parsing of `newline` and other such bytes in the read strings.

In researching this problem I've found various ways of handling multiple values in a single value context [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/multiple-values-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172), however none of these deal with the occurrence of mixed types. The idea of using an interface to deal with this has been suggested [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used/35966287#35966287), and has been attempted, but I am uncomfortable with the lengthy verbosity of the exisitng suggestions [3](http://blog.vladimirvivien.com/2014/03/hacking-go-filter-values-from-multi.html) and [4](https://play.golang.org/p/IwqmoKwVm-).

I wonder if there is an idiomatic way to ectively sort through a variety of typed values in a tidy fashion.

EDITED: First I established an interface, as suggested.  This seems a good idea, and is a commonly used trick from C if I recall.

```golang
func Use(vals ...interface{}) {
    i := 0
    p := []uint8{}  //I've replaced the alias "byte" with the native "uint8"
    var val uint8  //I've changed this declaration to a non-assigned declaration
    for i, val := range vals {
        if i < 1 {
            _ = val
            i++
        } else {
            p[i] = val.(uint8)
            return fmt.Print(p[i]) //please excuse the earlier typo
            //interestingly, this call to p[i] returns more than one value
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the essential code follows:

```golang
func other() (string, []byte) {
    a := "declared and not used"
    b := []byte("stuff")
    return a,b
}

func main() {
    Use(other())
}
```

It remains unbeknownst to me why this code should appear to have multiple values inside p[i]. Shouldn't the `blank identifier` used in the control loop make such a possibility unlikely?

The new error, from the edited code is reported as:
`invalid type assertion: x.(uint8) (non-interface type func(...interface {}) []interface {} on left)`

The original code can be found at:
https://play.golang.org/p/BEhOT7R0vvr

The edited code can be found at:
https://goplay.space/#SF7X7dx8yL9

Comment: Your playground link doesn't work. Your code isn't even valid (`fmt.printf` isn't exported)

Comment: The modified code actually also does not work, hence the question: https://goplay.space/#SF7X7dx8yL9

Comment: Please read the compiler error messages. They tell you what's wrong with your code. We're not here to read error messages to you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         return fmt.print(p[i]) 
>         //interestingly, this call to p[i] returns more than one value
> ```

No, it doesn't.

In fact, the compiler doesn't have any idea how many items it returns, because `fmt.printf` isn't exported, so it doesn't know what it is. All it knows is that it returns **one or more** values. But you're in a function with zero return values, thus the error.

It's unclear what you want, so I'm not sure how to suggest changing your code, but two potential answers seem obvious:

1. Stop returning something:

   ```
       fmt.Print(p[i])
       return
   ```
2. Change your function to return something, then call the proper function:

   ```
   func Use(vals ...interface{}) byte {
     // ... skip
         return p[i]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `Use(other())`, you're passing two arguments to `Use`'s variadic parameter: a `string`, and a `[]byte`. So when you iterate over them, the first iteration gives you the `string`, the second iteration gives you the `[]byte`. Also a lot of this code is unnecessary and should be failing (some at compile time, some at run time):

```
// this declares a variable in function scope that is never used; it's immediately shadowed
val := []byte("")
// this declares a *new* variable val in loop scope, shadowing the outer val
for i, val := range vals {
    if i < 1 {
        // this does absolutely nothing
        _ = val
        // this also does absolutely nothing - i is the loop iterator and is overwritten by range on every iteration
        i++
    } else {
        // this should be hard failing because there is no case where val is a byte; it's only ever string or []byte
        p[i] = val.(byte)
        // It's fmt.Print - fmt.print would be unexported and not usable
        return fmt.print(p[i])
    }
}
```