# Declared but not used

Tags: go, variables

I am new to Golang. I am confused why I got the error that `partial` is not used in the code below?

```golang
// Using var keyword
var partial string

for i, request := range requestVec {
    if i == (len(requestVec)-1) && !strings.Contains(request, "\r\n\r\n") {
        partial = request
        break
    }
}
```

I assign `request` to `partial` in the `if` statement.

Comment: But you do nothing with it....what's the point of assigning it  if you won't use it later?

Comment: I see. Is that what the error about?

Comment: It is an error to declare a variable without using it. You do not use `partial`, therefor you get this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid annoying error "declared and not used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743841/how-to-avoid-annoying-error-declared-and-not-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a compiler error in Go to declare a variable without using it.

In the code in you're example the variable `partial` is never used, only assigned, so is seen as unused. If you added additional code that read the variable then the error would be resolved. For example

```
var partial string

for i, request := range requestVec {
    if i == (len(requestVec)-1) && !strings.Contains(request, "\r\n\r\n") {
        partial = request
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(partial) // We are now using `partial`
```